# XCode - Could not load NIB file bundle

Tags: xcode, xib

I'm having some issues with XCode. I'm trying to load cells from nib files, but it's very strange. If I clean my project, sometimes one view will work, then another will fail to load, and if I do a re-clean they sometimes swap round.

Is there some cache folder in Xcode or temp files I can delete ? None of the common solutions on SO seem to be working for me.

```
2018-02-26 10:51:04.700364+0000 SpiceCentral[73982:3269187] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/james/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/2190BB99-8811-437E-B620-3B4F917B391F/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/F83C4BDA-F236-4C22-B95F-6539FB8A8595/SpiceCentral.app> (loaded)' with name 'descTableViewCell''*** First throw call stack:
```

The cell it's trying to load:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad(
    tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "descTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "descTableViewCell")
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let descCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "descTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! descTableViewCell
    return descCell
}
```

My descCell nib file:

[image]

I've tried cleaning my project, rebuilding. Closing Xcode, restarting my mac, using a new emulator.

Thanks,
J

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to fix it (or so it seems), by renaming the nib file and all references to it. I assume this isn't a good solution and there is a proper way to fix my problem. I've saved an older version of the project, and will leave this question open. I'll try fixes on the older version and mark the correct answer.